# Standalone Spring+Java+JMS

Tags: java, spring

I have two start scripts to run the standalone applications.

1. `startQueue.sh` for listening JMS messages and store the message into the Oracle Database Table.
2. `startProcess.sh` - Get the table information and process the data and delete the information from the database and terminate.

My question is when ever the JMS message inserted into the DB then automatically trigger and process the table information using timer.

Comment: You either trigger (when message is inserted) or use a timer, how would you want to use both?

Comment: I don't see a question here?

Answer (score 0):

You could just have the second application run constantly, polling the database, but I think that a better design would be to do it all in one step - receive the JMS message, insert it (if necessary), and then process it, all in one application.

Comment: You are correct, Grey. But the problem is, while processing the data if anything is goes wrong then we don't want to delete the data from the Database. Again we will need get and process the data upto it succeeds. once the database doesn't have any data then we will terminate. this process will automatically trigger when ever the database having the data. Can you please guide me which process follow.

Comment: read this - http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2012/04/database-as-queue-anti-pattern.html  Then, if you still feel that you must use the database as a work queue, your only option is going to be to have an outside process that continually queries the database to see if there is anything to process.

Comment: @user1941080 This situation is screaming for transaction management. Depending on the features of your message queue, you should be able to remove the message and process it in the database in one and the same transaction. If processing fails, you can subsequently put the message in a dead message queue perhaps?